# Importing large CSV to Oracle via TOAD

Tags: oracle, csv, bigdata, toad

I have a large CSV file (around 620,000,000 records) which I need to import into Oracle via Toad. It gives out of memory.

I have been able to split them into .xls files with single sheet in each. How can I upload data into a table from multiple xls files, or is there a better alternative?

Comment: Are you running out of memory on the client?  Or on the database?  Do you need to use Toad?  Or could you use `SQL*Loader` instead?  Do you really have a CSV file?  Or an XLS file?

Comment: You can try loading full file on first page, but with commit every row or some part of rows

Comment: Out of memory on the client, I have a CSV file originally.

Comment: You should use external tables: easy, fast ... only advantages with so little work :) ...

Comment: @Cyryl1972, tell me how?

Comment: Consult the Oracle documentation (https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e22490/et_concepts.htm#SUTIL011) or read this article from Tim Hall (https://oracle-base.com/articles/9i/external-tables-9i)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way is to use `SQL*LOADER`, and in TOAD there is an option Database->Import->`SQL*LOADER` wizard. One can directly specify the input file and the table in which records are to be inserted/appended.

A problem that may arise is the availability of sqlldr.exe when working on Oracle 10g Instant Client. For this, the user may download the Oracle Universal Installer, OUI, (the one for 11g will work too), and this provides sqlldr.exe. It needs to be added to the `SQL*LOADER` path in TOAD (View->Toad Options->Executables).

Finally, in case after installing the OUI there are problems starting TOAD (error related to NLS environment), create a system variable `NLS_LANG` with value `AMERICAN_AMERICA.WE8ISO8859P1`. This should fix TOAD connectivity issues.